# Ajax updating the first row in my form in php while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having a PHP while loop. Inside my while loop, I am having an HTML form. I am processing that form values through ajax into my PHP which then updates those values in my DB. The problem is whenever I submit that form it only updates the first fetched row in my table. I am also passing the unique Id through my form into ajax but for some reason, only the first row is keep getting updated.

My Php Code:

```
<?php
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($data as $row) { ?><form>
    <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['no'] ?>"><br>
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label>XYZ Question</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="NO">NO
            <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="YES">YES
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label>XYZ Question</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="optradio1" value="NO">NO
            <input type="radio" name="optradio1" value="YES">YES
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label>XYZ Question</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="optradio2" value="NO">NO
            <input type="radio" name="optradio2" value="YES">YES
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">SUBMIT</button>
</form><?php }
```

My Ajax Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 var launchAjax = function () { // event handler for button click
 $.post(
 "inbetween.php/",
  {
      id: $("[name=id]").val(),
      question: $("[name=optradio]:checked").val(),
      question1: $("[name=optradio1]:checked").val(),
      question2: $("[name=optradio2]:checked").val(),
  }
);
}
    $(".btn").click(launchAjax);
 });
```

My PHP SQL Query

```
 <?php

include 'common.php';

$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "id", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$question = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "optradio", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$question1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "optradio1", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$question2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "optradio2", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


function getMark($answer, $mark = 1){ 
    $result = 0;
    if($answer == 'YES'){
        $result = $mark;
    }
    return $result;
}

    $p = 0;
    $p += getMark($question, 1); 
    $p += getMark($question1, .5);
    $p += getMark($question2, 2);


$command1 = "UPDATE rating SET marks = marks + '$c', marks= marks/ totalNumber WHERE no = '$id'";

 // prepare and executing
$stmt1 = $dbh->prepare($command1);
$result = $stmt1->execute();

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using PDO, but your while loop seems to be using the mysqli approach, and if you are selecting multiple rows you use `fetchAll`, update your code as such:

```
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $id = $row['no'];
}
```

Update: if you want multiple forms, one for each row, you have to do it this way:

```
<?php
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($data as $row) { ?><form>
    <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['no'] ?>"><br>
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label>XYZ Question</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="NO">NO
            <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="YES">YES
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label>XYZ Question</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="optradio1" value="NO">NO
            <input type="radio" name="optradio1" value="YES">YES
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label>XYZ Question</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="optradio2" value="NO">NO
            <input type="radio" name="optradio2" value="YES">YES
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">SUBMIT</button>
</form><?php }
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll make it correct. But I still have the same problem.

Comment: Updated, check please

Comment: Don't forget to mention @stactoverflowsam1 when updating your answer :)

Comment: As the author, you will be notified any way :) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299935/1244597

Comment: @AamirR I have accepted the answer, But still, my first row is getting updated.

Comment: I am getting the right row id on each form but when I submit any row form, unfortunately, it only updates the value of the first row.

Comment: I dont see your update PHP script or your SQL, can you provide the SQL statement, edit your question

Comment: for sure, I'll provide you the sql script as well

Comment: @AamirR   I just checked In developer Console under network  that my ajax is not passing the unique id to my php

Comment: @AamirR so the problem is not in the sql query

Comment: yea, most certainly not, can you print `print_r($row)` to check whats the output